# PHP Url encode transition to non-url encode

Tags: php

In my file I have this line of code:

```
$amember_return_url = urlencode($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]);
```

That returns my domain name.

What I want to do, instead, is hardcode the domain+path.

So something like this:
$amember_return_url = "domain.com/path/";

But it's not working. I think because I still need to retain the 'urlencode' or something? I'm foreign to PHP so any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Data is being passed to another website and it's using the amember return url for a callback path. Currently it's using the domain + /path/ but the path is different on different websites. So instead, I want to use the amember return URL which already contains the path. So basically instead of making amember return url be the domain, I need it to be the domain + installation path, which in this case is domain.com/path/. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I went from the original string to this:
$amember_return_url = urlencode("domain.com/orders/");

And it stopped working. 

It works with the original string but on the other website I have to set my callbacks to look like this:
public function add_amember_refund() {

  $url = 'http://'.$_SESSION['get']['cb'].'/orders/api/invoice-refunds';

The 'cb' call is referencing the amember return url. So instead of that, I want to make the amember return url be domain.com/orders/, and the above line be $url = 'http://'.$_SESSION['get']['cb'].'api/invoice-refunds'; (see how I removed the /orders/